# Parsing special characters to default value of float type

Tags: java, parsing, jaxb, numberformatexception

I'm developing a web service which calls another one like that:

```
CalledService service = new CalledService();
CalledServicePortType portType = service.getCalledServicePort();
CalledServiceResult calledServiceResult = portType.getResults(request);  //NumberFormatException here when dot is returned
```

Of course I suppose that `getResults` will return an valid `CalledServiceResult` object.

My `CalledServiceResult` (just part of it):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CalledServiceResult", propOrder = {
//...
    "myFloat"
})
public class CalledServiceResult{
    //...
    @XmlElement(name = "myFloat")
    protected float myFloat;
    //...
}
```

However `CalledService` sometimes returns:

```
<myFloat>.</myFloat> <!-- dot instead of valid float -->
```

Which couse an `NumberFormatException` on marked line. That is obvious `CalledService's` error, however let's say I can't change it (it was developed by external company).

How I can modify my `CalledServiceResult` class to prepare it to this situation? I want to have `0.0` in my `myFloat` variable when `CalledService` will return `. (dot)`

One more thing, obvious solution is a change of `myFloat` type to `String`, however I'm doing lot of calculation later and I don't want to parse it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be resolved by having our own custom marshaling/unmarshaling logic. In the above scenario the data in the `<myFloat>.</myFloat>` is formatted as a float without any pre validation check.

We can provide our own marshaling and un marshaling implementation for a particular xml element of our Request/Response. All we have to do is to write a class extending the  [XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) by which we will provide the necessary logic in the [marshal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html#marshal(BoundType)) and [unmarshall()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html#unmarshal(ValueType)) method. We can map this adapter class to the property using the annotation [XmlJavaTypeAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html)

This is how your `CalledServiceResult` will look like now,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CalledServiceResult", propOrder = {
//...
    "myFloat"
})
public class CalledServiceResult{
    //...
    @XmlElement(name = "myFloat")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyFloatAdapter.class)
    protected float myFloat;
    //...
}

public class MyFloatAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Float> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(Float myFloat) throws Exception {
        return Float.toString(myFloat);
    }

    @Override
    public Float unmarshal(String myFloatString) throws Exception {
        return (myFloatString == ".") ? 0.0 : Float.parseFloat(myFloatString);
    }
}
```